# Update value in Dictionary with multiple values per key

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary with multiple 16 digit keys, each has 5 values assigned to it to later be printed in a nicely formatted column. I'm running each key through a couple functions, and wanted to update the values as it happens, leaving the rest as they were.

ex:

```
ccDict={"111111111111111111":("N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A")}
```

printed after running through functions:

```
CardNumber                 Length   Prefix   SumDbleEvenPlace  SumOddPlace       Valid?    
11111111111111111111111        19       N/A      N/A               N/A               No
```

I'm having trouble updating and changing specific values, and haven't been able to find much documentation online. Is there no way to update one of the specific values, and leaving the rest as they are? I'd be ok with transferring t

Comment: a tuple is immutable so you cannot update the values in place

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a list instead of a tuple for your values. Then you can do this:

```
ccDict={"111111111111111111":["N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A"]}
ccDict['111111111111111111'][0] = "new value"
ccDict
{'111111111111111111': ['new value', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A']}
```

If you insist on using a tuple, you can do this:

```
ccDict={"111111111111111111":("N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A")}
new_values = list(ccDict['111111111111111111'])
new_values[0] = "new value"
ccDict['111111111111111111'] = tuple(new_values)
ccDict['111111111111111111']
('new value', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A')
```

Since it sounds like you're having trouble initializing the ccDict values as well, you can do something like this:

```
for k in my_list:
    ccDict[k] = [str(len(k)), "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "No"]
```

if `my_list` is your list of cc values.

Comment: Yeah the list instead of the tuples makes perfect sense, and works with the table already. Thanks. How could I iterate with it, though? First I'm transferring already failed cards to the dictionary, and that command only initializes. was originally using:

     ccDict[w]=(str(len(w)), "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "No") 

under the loop. Again, thanks so much.

Comment: Happy to help :) I'm not entirely sure what your asking though in this comment... Do you mean how can you loop through all of the keys in your ccDict? You can use `for k in ccDict.keys(): ...` to do that. I will update my answer to give an example of iterating through the keys.

Comment: Hi, what I mean is that I have a list of numbers, and am using a for loop to add each one to my dictionary. The command you listed doesn't iterate, but creates the dictionary with that single entry each time it's called. I've been messing with it a bit to try and it get it working, but no dice.

Comment: OK I think I see. I'll update the loop example I gave :)

Comment: Alright, latest edit worked perfect. I guess my issue was not taking off the curly brackets for the dictionary. Thanks dude, you're a lifesaver.